# Android Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'support_version' for object

Tags: android, gradle

I have a modification I want to do to android settings in order for it to be compatible with older versions so I added to the dependencies

```
 implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
    //implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
```

This produced the error

```
Could not get unknown property 'support_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I added the following to the top of the build.gradle file also

```
plugins {
    id  'com.android.application'
    id  'kotlin-android'
    id  'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Please what am I doing wrong?
In order to progress I had to comment the two lines out so that the android can compile but I need to make it backward compatible in production.Android

Answer (score 0):

**Try with below dependency In App gridle File**

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

**Project level Gridle File**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
     dependencies {
             classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
                 }
           }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

com.android.support is deprecated. Replace by androidx

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `"support_version"` variable in your Gradle script.

Try this:

add this to your build.gradle

```
ext.main = ['support_version'      : 'X.X.X']
```

and in your dependency structure, you can add.

```
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${main.support_version}"
```

NB: make sure you have valid version number.